# Time differences between windows and ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7, time

I'm running a tri-boot setup with Windows 7, ubuntu 12.04, and Backtrack 5 all running on separate partitions. When ever I boot into windows after linux the time is all messed up and I have to manually reset it. The same happens the other way around. How do I fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Clock time is off by 4 hours](http://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-by-4-hours)

Comment: Read this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because Windows doesn't do UTC. Refer to [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Make_Windows_use_UTC).

Comment: Thanks! In your opinion, what do you think would be better, making windows UTC or Linux local?

Comment: UTC is the better way to go ;)

Answer (score 1):

> Changing Linux to use local time is easier and more reliable than
>   changing Windows to use UTC, so dual-boot Linux/Windows systems tend
>   to use local time.

This is mentioned in the link provided. So I guess we have to make Ubuntu use hardware clock as local time.