# How do I set my clock in Windows to UTC / localtime?

Tags: dual-boot, windows, time

I have a dual boot and a I configured windows to use UTC with a registry fix as explained in here: [Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/ubuntu-12-04-clocktime-is-off-by-4-hours)

Now, I need to come back to localtime again, and I have no idea about how to edit the windows' registry to make it use local time again.

Comment: What version of Windows?

Comment: This question is asking for help reversing changes explained in [a procedure documented in an Ask Ubuntu answer and in the Ubuntu community wiki](http://askubuntu.com/a/169384/22949). Ordinarily Windows questions should be closed as off-topic, but in this case, I do not think we should close this as off-topic. However, it might be reasonable to add information about how to reverse the Windows registry edit in [that answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/169384/22949) to that answer itself, and then make this a duplicate of that question.

Comment: @EliahKagan Would it be better to add it also to the wiki, so the content is there for all?

Comment: @EliahKagan It is added, and was easier than expected. The DWORD value should have been set to 0 to undo it.

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ Cool--thanks for adding it to the community wiki!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On my Windows 7 machine, the default is for `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation\RealTimeIsUniversal` to *not exist*. So, here are Windows instructions:

Hold down the Windows logo key and press <kbd>R</kbd>. There, type `regedit`. Click OK and if you're using Vista or newer, acknowledge the UAC warning.

Now, in the left pane, there is a tree view.  Under `Computer`, there will be some things called `HKEY_SOMETHING_OR_OTHER`. You should click the + next to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`. Then, you should click the + next to `SYSTEM` to get ino `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM`. Now, expand `CurrentControlSet`, then inside it, `Control`, and then `TimeZoneInformation`. Now, right-click the entry for `RealTimeIsUniversal` and select the option to delete it. Alternatively, you could set it's value to 0.

Comment: Worked fine (in my case it was Windows XP). Thanks for the answer and for adding it to the wiki to make it available for everyone!

Comment: Note that this registry setting is no longer honored in Windows 8+.

Comment: @brianary I do not own any versions of Windows beyond 7. You are free to either suggest an edit to this answer, or create a new answer if you find a method that works with Windows 8.

Comment: @hexafraction I wish i knew of any. So far, all signs point to this being a completely dropped feature.

Comment: You just have to create the entry yourself in windows 8. Works fine.

Comment: @brianary the setting works fine on Windows 8.1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bwo5O.png

Comment: @Stijn What edition of Windows 8.1 are you using? It doesn't work on mine, but I'm using the basic/home edition.

Comment: @brianary I'm using Pro. Perhaps it's disabled in the basic edition then.

Comment: …and it still doesn't work in Windows 10. 

Comment: If hexafraction's answer didn't work, you're probably running a x64 Windows. You need to go thru the same steps, but create a `QWORD` value (instead of DWORD).