# Xubuntu - wrong time displayed

Tags: xubuntu, 16.04, time, xfce-panel, timezone

I'm at my wits' end. Using Xubuntu 16.04 and all I want is getting the correct time displayed in my top right corner.

But no matter what I do, I keep getting it wrong. I have tried both 'Datetime' and 'Orage Panel Clock', without any success. The system is configured to timezone 'Europe/Berlin' and it updates via NTP (tried others in the same zone, e.g. Europe/Amsterdam and Europe/Copenhagen'), nothing seems to work though.

I have tried individually changing the timezones for Orage and Datetime, uninstalling & reinstalling both, reinstalling NTP, but nothing changes.

I've got a parallel installation of Windows 8.1 for Photoshop and the occasional game; the time is displayed correctly there.

Any ideas before I go completely crazy?
Screenshot here:

[image: Both indicators + actual CEST from Google]

Comment: Have you tried any of the "related" questions here on the left, at least two of them desribe a similar problem to yours.
http://askubuntu.com/questions/305313/system-time-keeps-resetting-to-utc?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in Xubuntu 19.10.

Try this:

1. Right-click on "Time panel", select Panel -> Panel Settings...
2. Show window Panel Settings, select bookmark "Items", in this menu select Time.
3. Double-click to "Time" or select "Time" and click the gear icon to show new window Time.
4. In this window is a "Local Time" textbox.
5. I am from Czech Republic and my time in Time panel is the same as your - wrong time 
   (local time -1 hour).
6. I incorrectly write to textbox "Local Time" only "Prague".
7. I fix this text to "Europe/Prague" and now, on "Time panel" it shows the  right value for time.