# How to solve date and time problem in a system with both Windows 8 and Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, time

I have installed Ubuntu in my system last week which was defaultly installed with Windows 8. Whenever I boot to Windows after a visit to Ubuntu the date and time has changed and vice versa. I have to change the date and time every time when I boot to the OS.Help me to solve this issue..

Comment: This question already has an answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-by-4-hours