# Ubuntu won't boot after updating time

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, time

I have a laptop that is a dual boot Windows 8/Ubuntu 12.04 machine. I recently noticed that while in Windows, my system time was off. I tried to change it from within Windows but it reset every time I rebooted. My first thought was that the CMOS battery was bad but the clock was working just fine in Ubuntu.

I double checked the BIOS and since the clock was off there, I adjust the time and rebooted.

Now, Ubuntu no longer boots.

I'm very new to Ubuntu (just got it installed and working for the first time Tuesday) so I have no idea where to go from here. Any help would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Pls be clear about yopur problem!

Comment: CHange the Battery (BIOS Battery)

Comment: The time is being kept just fine... it just was set to the wrong time. Do you think it's still the CMOS battery?

Comment: @RubanSavvy - I'd love to be clearer. What more do you need?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I think I figured it out. Well, enough to get past it anyway...

Apparently Ubuntu stores the UTC time to the system time in the BIOS and Windows stores the local time. If the system time reads 12:00PM, Ubuntu adjusts to display the correct time for your time zone. For example, Central Time is UTC-6 so it would read the 12:00PM system time and subtract the 6 hours for me and show 6:00AM.

Windows on the other hand saves the local time. So if I save the clock to show 6:00AM in Windows, Ubuntu will no longer display the correct time. I have no idea why this causes Ubuntu not to boot AT ALL but it is what it is...

I got Ubuntu back up and running by using boot-repair. I booted to an Ubuntu install disc and typed this from the terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)
```

Then I selected Recommended Repair and restarted once it was finished.

There's a way to either force Ubuntu to treat the system time as the local time or force Windows to treat it as UTC time. This link showed me how to do that:

[Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-by-4-hours)

Comment: The installation process used to ask if the system clock was kept in local time or UTC - most likely for this exact reason.  I don't know if it still does.