# Can I Install ubuntu 14.04LTS alongside Windows Vista?

Tags: boot, windows-vista

Will Ubuntu 14 work alongside Windows Vista (on a PC), or do I need to choose Ubuntu 13 or 12 instead?

Comment: Yeah, why not. It is very possible... Check out his @karel's link above

Comment: You can choose 12

Answer (score 0):

You can choose 12.04 or 14.04 but not 13 because all versions of 13 (13.04 and 13.10) have reached EOL just like WindowsXP so they are no longer supported. 12.04 and 14.04 are LTS or long term support versions and will be supported for a few years.

[image]

Picture from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ubuntu_releases

Answer (score 0):

There should not be any restrictions for installing specific Operating Systems depending on any OS you have yet installed.

Maybe - or even probably - you have to make some adjustments (e.g. [adjusting the clock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off)). But the system works.