# Clock showing wrong time

Tags: time, clock, timezone

This is not a duplicate of **[Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot).  This is a TimeZone Bug!**

My clock on top panel shows time different from time i set or synched through internet. It began after changing to winter time. Here's the screenshot so you can understand what I mean: [image]

If I change timezone I get correct time in that timezone but can't fix my one. Is it some sort of bug? How to fix it?

Edit: yes, I have Windows in dualboot. How does it affect the clock?

Edit2: so, I currently changed to Shanghai time which is the same timezone but clock is now correct. But still, Irkutsk is showing wrong time.

Comment: Does this machine dual boot Windows? Please edit your question with this information.

Comment: See http://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot for a possible explanation and solution. If this is the reason, please delete this question as a duplicate. If not, please edit the question with new information.

Answer (score 2):

The Irkutsk time being wrong is a bug, which is supposed to be "fixed" and "released".  See [Launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata/+bug/1377813) for the whole history of this Time Zone update.

**However**, for some or other reason, the TZDATA does not get released to my version of Ubuntu (14.04) so I installed the Debian fix (released!) myself:

Steps to follow:

1. Go to [Debian tzdata FTP repository](ftp://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/t/tzdata/)
2. Download:

   - `tzdata_2014h-0squeeze1_all.deb`
   - `tzdata-java_2014h-0squeeze1_all.deb`
3. `sudo dpkg --install tzdata_2014h-0squeeze1_all.deb tzdata-java_2014h-0squeeze1_all.deb`
4. Log out and log back in

**The above files are tested on Ubuntu 14.04 only.** (My own machine)  I have no clue what this will do for future TZ updates to your machine, so I would be careful if doing this in an international environment with multiple servers!  (On the other hand: it's just *data*, not an *application*)

Comment: @scherdee: As you're a reputation 13 user: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Думе нашей спасибо скажи. 
Recent changes in time zones in Russia made everything go haywire. Again. 
Better set timezone manually until package `tzdata` updates again to accomodate this. 
Package `tzdata` contains info about timezones, winter time and stuff.
To change timezone low-level, in terminal do

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

However, you will need to at least switch off "use automatic time" or however is it called now.

Comment: Another problem is that I can't set time manually, changes just don't affect clock.

Comment: Updated to solve the comment.

Comment: It's definetly not related with tzdata but with that clock widget on top panel http://i.imgur.com/LA95fjQ.png

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected with internet then go to time and date settings and click on any other country on the map , then wait for time change then again click on your country ....

Comment: I did it few times. Bug only affects my timezone and doesn't go away.

Comment: YOU ARE TELLING IT'S NOT CHANGING YOUR DATE AND TIME ?

Comment: see the difference: http://i.imgur.com/PVybq4N.png?1 and http://i.imgur.com/OfPZoRL.png

Comment: You have not selected the option of clock to be updated with network. select it first

Comment: It changes nothing and bug is still there. I tried that and many other ways to fix clock before posting the question, so trust me.

Comment: Did you unpicked time in other location option?