# How to fix time error after dual booted Ubuntu 15.04 with Windows 8.1?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-8, time, 15.04

I recently dual booted my laptop in ubuntu 15.04 with Win 8.1. But every time when I open windows it shows a different time!!!

[windows time zone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBsxF.jpg)

windows time is set to UTC, and Ubuntu time is also set to UTC.
how can i fix it???

Comment: Your Windows time is set to UTC + 5:30 according to the image you linked.

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot

Comment: @Pilot6 the link description didn't work :(

Comment: Problem solved..