# Unsolvable Ubuntu 15.10 problems

Tags: unity, drivers, ppa, bug-reporting, multiple-monitors

I am relatively new to Linux. I have opened some questions here during my quest to keep Ubuntu as a main OS anyway. I managed to sustain a seemingly redundant installation and everything seems to work fine. Now except some small stuff that no matter how much I searched on the web I couldn't find a solution or the solutions.

I have a relatively new computer, here can find my specs:

```
cpu AMD FX 8320,
GTX 650 Ti 2GB,
16 GB 2400MHz ram,
Asrock 970 pro rev2.0 (Windows 10 ready)
120GB SSD
```

My SSD is partitioned as follow:

- `sda1` as my grub partition 750 MB
- `sda2` as a boot partition ext2 filesystem
- `sda3` as main OS ext4 filesystem
- `sda4` as a swap partition

I found this things didn't work for me:

1. some PPA package;
2. numlock always off at start;
3. dual monitor display issues;
4. system monitor doesn't work;
5. not able to install windows fonts;
6. system clock not synchronized;

**TL;DR Errors explanation:**

1. some ppas that are given from the official developer sites (or from Ubuntu forums) for ubuntu 15.10 sometimes don't work (e.g. QtSixA app for recognize a PS3 sixaxis controller).
2. the NUMLOCK is always OFF when I boot/restart/logoff my computer and no terminal commands or 3rd part software seems to work.
3. I have a 2 monitor display and I have setted both in Ubuntu settings and in my graphics driver settings (Nvidia 352) to launch apps on monitor B and set it as the main monitor also tried to make the same setting by downloading `CompizConfig`. (I didn't do all the steps together: first just changed Ubuntu settings but no result except in the the session; I changed the setting next reboot while the setting didn't change still programs did ignore it and launch on monitor A, searched and found the similar setting in my graphics driver and again no change. Also changed settings in `CompizConfig` and again no change except the first session I did the change).
4. System monitor doesn't work!! Its a native app that is supposed to monitor the resources of the computer. Well it seems it does, but actually it does NOT (I have set it to show all processes + their dependencies) and there are numerous times were CPU Cores are USED like on 80% yet the process tab doesn't show any app using any % of the CPU (or a few just using 1% or so depends on the session) **OR** the CPU is used  and system monitor doesn't show that its used or does show that its used less than 1% were the tasks at hand running(like chess engines etc) and the temperatures don't excuse such low usage and suggest that the CPU is used significantly more than system monitor suggests. **OR** Ubuntu lags because it uses (at 100% constantly) only one (of 8 available) cpu cores (And still at process tab it doesn't show any process using even that one core resources) that could be a Ubuntu issue.
   I knwo that CPU microcode from AMD is installed.
5. Fonts for windows NEVER get installed in my computer every time I get a message about installing them when I click to "perform this action" they seem to get downloaded (by what I can see from the terminal window that is popping) but they never do. Or if they do the error message about them not being installed pops up periodically.
6. The system clock gets messed up for example if the computer gets disconnected from the internet (I have it set to get time from internet ) and my mobos clock works fine so I don't know why it messes up that much... that leads to other problems since some procedures need or compare the time and date. This obviously doesn't happen every day, but it happens more than it really should.

The computer runs flawlessly Windows for few years up until I formatted the SSD containing it and installed Ubuntu. So I don't suppose that the above problems are caused because my hardware is faulty.

I post this here in desperate hope of a miracle.

*P.S. I've already watched at Google first page results.*

Comment: Why you don't put all this issue in different questions?

Comment: For some of them I did (like the system monitor) but never got an answer and never found one or the ones I found dont fix the issue as I said. this post is more like a protest..

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We're sorry, but Ask Ubuntu is not a forum, but a Question & Answer site: it works best if you ask one question, so you can receive one answer. When you ask multiple questions, you need to find one expert versed in multiple areas, which becomes unlikelier the more questions you put into, well, one question! ;-) So please, split up your question into multiple questions and drop me a comment so I can answer one of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

On StackExchange networks, it's generally best to post each question separately. I don't have answers to all your issues, but here are some random info that might help:

> 1) some ppas that are given from the official developer sites (or fomr
>   ubuntu forums) for ubuntu 15.10 sometimes dont work.... (most recent
>   in my experience was the QtSixA app for recognize a PS3 sixaxis
>   controller)

PPAs are *very* liberal in allowing anyone to put up packages. No one, including Canonical, can monitor and make sure everything works. As part of the community, you are strongly encouraged to help the PPA owners resolve their issues, or if they ignore you, to point out to others that the PPA is buggy.

Generally speaking, try to stay clear of random PPAs. For the same reason you wouldn't download random files on the internet and execute them, you shouldn't do that on Linux either. Some PPAs are from official developers of a well-known project, such as wine. Those are fine. But if some shady person on the internet suggests a random PPA for something, well you'd better be careful!

For experimental/unstable libraries/programs that aren't yet good enough to be included in the main repositories of Debian (and inherited by Ubuntu), it often makes sense to download the source and build/install it. There is usually a brief set of instructions on how to do this, and is not so hard.

Finally, if stability is what you are looking for, you might want to stick to LTS releases of Ubuntu. You'd miss out on "the latest stuff", but the latest stuff is exactly what's not as well-tested.

> 2) the NUMLOCK is always OFF when I boot/restart/loggoff my computer
>   and no terminal commands or 3rd part software seems to work -and I
>   find this ridiculous!!!

Is it only the LED that is off, or the numpad doesn't switch modes? Or does it turn on when you click it, but is off by default? I just looked at my keyboard and the LED was off, I pressed NUMLOCK, it stayed off, and pressing again it got on. It looks like the NUMLOCK was actually on in the beginning, but it was just the LED that was off. It's a bug for sure. However, I'm sure it only affects *some* keyboards. Incidentally, my keybaord is microsoft.

> 3) I have a 2 monitor display and have set BOTH in ubuntu settings and
>   in my graphics driver settings (Nvidia 352) to launch apps on monitor
>   B and set it as the main monitor also tried to make the same setting
>   by downloading compizconfig (I didnt do all the steps together first
>   just changed ubuntu settings -no result except the in the session I
>   changed the setting next reboot while the setting didnt change still
>   programs did ignore it and launch on monitor A, searched and found the
>   similar setting in my graphics driver again no change... change the
>   settings in compiz again no change except the first session I did the
>   change) -I find that ridiculous as well... I mean its a BASIC
>   graphical element I know that a userfriendlies etc of a free distro
>   shouldnt be compared with proprietary OS such as macOS and windows...
>   but I still find this a fundamental issue that shouldnt exist in the
>   15th edition of the ubuntuOS..

I have the same problem on Ubuntu 14.04 at work too. For me though, it's only for fullscreen applications (Quake 3 under wine). I agree that it's frustrating. I'm not sure if it's an Nvidia bug, or Unity. If it's Nvidia's, it's not too surprising. Giving them the benfit of the doubt, they only recently started supporting Linux.

> 4) an other elemental issue that shouldnt exist... system monitor
>   doesnt work!! Its a native app that is supposed to monitor the
>   resources of the computer... well it SEEMS it does but actually it
>   does NOT (I have set it to show all processes + their dependencies)
>   and there are numerous times were CPU Cores are USED like on 80% yet
>   the process tab doesnt show any app using any % of the CPU (or a few
>   just using 1% or so depends on the session)
>
> OR
>
> the CPU is used and system monitor doesnt show that its used or does
>   show that its used less than 1% were the tasks at hand running(like
>   chess engines etc) and the temperatures dont excuse such low usage and
>   suggest that the CPU is used significantly more than system monitor
>   suggests...
>
> OR
>
> Ubuntu lags because it uses (at 100% constantly) only one (of 8
>   available) cpu cores (And still at process tab it doesnt show any
>   process using even that one core resources... ) that could be a Ubuntu
>   issue
>
> to cut the long story short system monitor seems to be more than a
>   graphical gimmick than a real deal resource monitor... again I find
>   this a basic elemental thing (to be able to know exactly or in a very
>   close approximation how many resources are being used and which
>   processes use them) and find the absence of that function ridiculous
>   for a OS no matter if free or not.
>
> P.S I have updated and installed the cpu microcode from amd.

I believe System Monitor is more targeted at grandmothers, trying to be simple and everything. I use indicator-multiload to monitor my system activity (and while System Monitor doesn't show all process usages correctly, indicator-multiload generates correct graphs).

```
$ sudo apt-get install indicator-multiload
$ indicator-multiload &
```

After the above command, indicator-multiload should start on boot automatically. To actually see the processes and their usages, the good old `top` command (run from terminal) is the best. People generally think the terminal is for advanced users, but in reality, the terminal is just a very effective way of doing things on your computer. The windows terminal is so bad, people migrating from there aren't used to it. Trust me, you would feel easier there for *some* tasks.

> 5) Fonts for windows NEVER get installed in my computer every time I
>   get a message about installing them when I click to "perform this
>   action" they seem to get downloaded (by what I can see from the
>   terminal window that is popping) but they never do... or if they do
>   the error message about them not being installed pops up
>   periodically...

Sorry to hear that. I personally have no love for windows or its fonts, so I've never tried this. Perhaps somebody else has an opinion.

> 6) the REBOOT process or SHUTDOWN process is SO SO SO buggy (not even
>   windows 95 or earlier versions sucked that much in that) its like boot
>   and pray that no error message will appear or that it will boot
>   because you cant tell if it messed anything up since your last
>   shutdown.
>
> I have a relatively new computer (cpu amd fx 8320,GTX 650 Ti 2GB,16 GB
>   2400MHz ram,Asrock 970 pro rev2.0 -windows 10 ready-mobo running the
>   latest bios and run the OS on a 120GB SSD with sda1 as my grub
>   partition -750 MB- sda2 as a boot partition ext2 filesystem and sda3
>   as main OS ext4 filesystem and sda4 as a swap partition and dont run
>   any other OS on that disk)

What problems do you see? If you are interested in knowing exactly what's going on at boot and shutdown, you can edit your grub config to remove splash screen from boot.

```
$ sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
```

Find the line that says `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="..."` and remove `quiet splash` from it. Update your grub:

```
$ sudo update-grub
```

You can also see boot logs with `dmesg`:

```
$ dmesg
```

Many times, a minor error written during splash screen is not really a problem. Perhaps it's something some power user may care about, but generally if your system boots, you are ok. Linux hardly "messes anything up" during shutdown, so whatever is the cause of the error, it is very likely hardware related. It's impossible to tell without you providing info on what error you actually see.

Why is your boot partition ext2 by the way?

Side note: Since you have an SSD, you might be interested in reading [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Solid_State_Drives) for example to help improve its performance under Linux.

> 7) The system clock gets messed up for example if the computer gets
>   disconnected from the internet (I have it set to get time from
>   internet ) and my mobos clock works fine so I dont know why it messes
>   up that much... that leads to other problems since some procedures
>   need or compare the time and date.... this obviously doesnt happen
>   every day... but it happens more than it really should.

How does it get messed up? Linux (like all sane operating systems, which naturally excludes windows) keeps time in UTC. Windows keeps time in local time. I'm not going to go over just how stupid it is to use local time, but just letting you know that unless you live in the +0 timeline, the Linux and windows times are going to differ. If you boot into windows, it will change your motherboard's time to local time. Linux fixes it back to UTC. In dualboot systems, this is actually a problem. You can [try telling windows to use UTC](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot), but in my experience sometimes windows ignores your configuration. Alternatively, you can tell Linux to use local time, but I personally recommend not to do this (because local time is just stupid).

From your explanation, it doesn't seem like you are dual booting. So my suggestion is this. In Linux, fix the time (from the internet), then reboot and go to your bios. If it shows your local time, it's your motherboard that is somehow reverting the time back to local time. I've never seen a motherboard actually do this, but perhaps new "windows 10 ready" motherboards do it. This is unless, of course, you are booting into windows, and that's why your clock gets off.

> The computer runs flawlessly Windows for few years up until I
>   formatted the ssd containing it to install ubuntu.... so I dont
>   suppose that the above problems are caused because my hardware is
>   faulty.

Don't be so quick to think the hardware is not faulty. Unfortunately for you and me, many manufacturers only test their hardware with windows. That means that if there is a bug in the hardware that doesn't trigger because windows doesn't use a feature or follows a certain set of steps, the bug is often not discovered until someone runs Linux on it and it starts doing things differently ([random link after a quick search](https://mjg59.dreamwidth.org/22855.html)).

The best you can, again as part of the community, is to report your issues. Linux works with almost anything you throw at it, so unless the hardware came from a very anti-linux company and was released just yesterday, there is almost always someone taking care of each driver, and they may be interested in test reports.

> I post this here in desperate hope of a miracle
>
> Such as a very advanced member notices it and will read atleast one of
>   ht problems mentions above and give a different method to solve the
>   problem (different that the google results of the first page when
>   searching for them since they didnt work for me)
>
> Or that it gets noticed by the Ubuntu team and those problems get
>   fixed....

Just a final note. I've had similarly frustrating issues with windows (7 in particular, it was my last) in the past. For example, it not installing if I have two HDDs plugged at the same time, filling up my disk when updating then on restart showing the disk as it used to be, random black rectangle on the screen that doesn't go away until reboot, etc. For [a company that pours billions into making sure it keeps its monopoly of desktop OS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Criticism_of_Microsoft), its OS is really not less problematic than GNU/Linux. Before getting invested in Ubuntu, feel free to try out a couple of other GNU/Linux distros and perhaps most of your problems may go away. Ubuntu hasn't been "the best" distro for some time now.

While I too hope that one day GNU/Linux, any flavor, runs flawlessly, the fact is that no OS in the world can. Mac OS may run with less problems because it supports exclusively a handful of hardware pieces from Apple. Windows problems are less visible because often people buy PCs/laptops that come with windows pre-installed and tested. The fact that GNU/Linux runs on par with the other OSes (and in my opinion functionally much better, aside from minor bugs) and is entirely made up of free software (partly supported by various companies) is an amazing feat. All anyone can do is to help make GNU/Linux even better, whether it is through bug reports, suggestions or code. You have just begun doing just this, so, welcome to the community!