# Wrong Universal time on my Ubuntu server

Tags: server, time, timezone

On Ubuntu server the time is wrong:

Time from Google:

UTC: `Wednesday, May 18, 2016 5:31 AM (UTC)`

Asia\Riyadh: `Wednesday, May 18, 2016 8:31 AM (GMT+3)`

Time on my server `timedatectl`:

```
      Local time: Wed 2016-05-18 11:27:27 AST
  Universal time: Wed 2016-05-18 08:27:27 UTC
        RTC time: Wed 2016-05-18 08:27:27
       Time zone: Asia/Riyadh (AST, +0300)
 Network time on: yes
NTP synchronized: no
 RTC in local TZ: no
```

Note: I am not dual booting with Windows. Ubuntu Server is the only OS on my server.

Comment: Is your computer a dual-boot computer?  For example, Ubuntu and Windows?  If so, take a look at this:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime .  Scroll down to "Multiple Boot Systems Time Conflicts".  A similar question on this site (with the same site as the answer):  http://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot .

Answer (score 6):

Install the network time protocol daemon. This will allow you to sync your system time over the internet.

```
sudo apt install ntp ntpdate
```

Once installed, run the following command:

```
ntpdate pool.ntp.org
```

This will link your computer with the time servers of the NTP Pool Project. For me my clocks fixed themselves quickly after running the command. And that was it.
After running the following command and setting the system clock, run:

```
hwclock --systohc
```

Comment: The program 'ntpdate' is currently not installed.

Comment: The program 'pacman' is currently not installed.

Comment: I fixed the commands in the post of User123 - please re-try now

Comment: Is there a solution other than installing `pacman` and the deprecated `ntpdate`?

Comment: Simply installing ntp and let the service run should be enoough from my point of view. Forget about pacman - that was a false advice by User123

Comment: After running commands and then restarting, it solved my Ubuntu 16.04 UTC time

Comment: just minor: the two `ntpdate` and `hwclock` commands need `sudo`