# Clock shows wrong time after switching from Ubuntu to Windows 10

Tags: 16.04, windows-10, time

I have dual booted Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 in UEFI mode (secure boot off). My time in BIOS is correct.

When I boot into Ubuntu and then boot into Windows 10, it shows the wrong time. I have to correct it manually or by the internet in Windows 10, and when I reboot into Windows 10 then it is not a problem. The clock will show the correct time. And then when I reboot to Linux the clock is correct, but switching back to Windows 10 the clock messes up again.

Comment: Ubuntu is set for UTC time and Windows is not.  You need to set your Windows for UTC time as well.   Check out http://superuser.com/questions/185773/does-windows-7-support-utc-as-bios-time

Comment: thanks [Terrance](http://askubuntu.com/users/231142/terrance). I had asked this question on windows forums and they are just making me move round and round and then they left it unanswered

Comment: Take a look at this as well : http://askubuntu.com/q/169376/295286  Frequent issue with dual boot

Comment: Not a problem.  It's best to leave Ubuntu at UTC and set Windows to UTC.  I have done it and noticed no problems.  =)

Comment: my bios time is not correct what should i do?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

[Multiple Boot Systems Time Conflicts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts)

> Operating systems store and retrieve the time in the hardware clock
>   located on your motherboard so that it can keep track of the time even
>   when the system does not have power. Most operating systems
>   (Linux/Unix/Mac) store the time on the hardware clock as **UTC** by
>   default, though some systems (notably Microsoft Windows) store the
>   time on the hardware clock as the **'local' time**. This causes problems
>   in a dual boot system if both systems view the hardware clock
>   differently.
>
> The advantage of having the hardware clock as UTC is that you don't
>   need to change the hardware clock when moving between timezones or
>   when Daylight Savings Time (DST) begins or ends as UTC does not have
>   DST or timezone offsets.
>
> Changing Linux to use local time is easier and more reliable than
>   changing Windows to use UTC, so dual-boot Linux/Windows systems tend
>   to use local time.
>
> Since Intrepid (8.10), UTC=yes is default.
>
> ### Solution 1: Make Windows use UTC
>
> **Note**: This method was not initially supported on Windows Vista and
>   Server 2008, but came back with Vista SP2, Windows 7, Server 2008 R2
>   and Windows 8/8.1.
>
> To make MS Windows calculate the time from the hardware clock as UTC.
>
> Create a file named [WindowsTimeFixUTC.reg](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime?action=AttachFile&do=view&target=WindowsTimeFixUTC.reg) with the following contents
>   and then double click on it to merge the contents with the registry:
>
> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
>  "RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001
> ```
>
> **Note**: Windows Time service will still write local time to the RTC
>   regardless of the registry setting above on shutdown, so it is handy
>   to disable Windows Time service with this command (if time sync is
>   still required while in Windows use any third-party time sync
>   solution):
>
> ```
> sc config w32time start= disabled
> ```
>
> If running the above command in Powershell, you'll have to specify sc.exe:
>
> ```
> sc.exe config w32time start= disabled
> ```
>
> #### Reversing the change
>
> You can create a file with the following contents and then
>   double-click it to merge in the original changes, as above:
>
> ```
> Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
>
> [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]
>  "RealTimeIsUniversal"=-
> ```
>
> If Windows Time service was disabled, enable it again with the
>   command:
>
> ```
> sc config w32time start= demand
> ```
>
> ### Solution 2: Make Linux use 'Local' time
>
> To tell your Ubuntu system that the hardware clock is set to 'local'
>   time:
>
> Pre-Ubuntu 15.04 systems (e.g. Ubuntu 14.04 LTS):
>
> 1. edit /etc/default/rcS
> 2. add or change the following section
>
>    ```
>    # Set UTC=yes if your hardware clock is set to UTC (GMT)
>    UTC=no
>    ```
>
> Ubuntu 15.04 systems and above (e.g. Ubuntu 16.04 LTS):
>
> 1. open a terminal and execute the following command
>
>    ```
>    timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
>    ```

source: [Ubuntu Help](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts)

Comment: Hi, have you try this on Windows 10 64bit also? There should be used not "dword" but "qword". Source: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/time-differences-ubuntu-1604-windows-10/

Comment: I had tried it on Windows 10 a year ago.... This worked then ... Can't say about now however, it most probably will work

Comment: Is it safe/ok to disable Windows Time service? What does it do? If it disables time internet sync than it would be bad to disable it

Comment: I have a dual boot setup with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04. Before doing anything, Ubuntu would display the clock correctly and Windows would display a wrong clock. Making Windows use UTC and turning off the Windows time service didn't work, it made Windows display the right time while Ubuntu displayed a wrong one. But making Ubuntu use local time made both display the same correct time.

Comment: i have the same problem but i noticed that Bios has the wrong time that the windows10 displays (only after i had previously booted in Linux). I tried changing the Bios time but when i go back it's the false one every time....

Comment: Should this change the time instantly? My time is off by an hour after using Windows 10 but timedatectl set-local-rtc 1 or timedatectl set-local-rtc 0 does not make any difference.