# Diplay time in win 7 reversed in 2 hours back , after operation ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot

I am working in dual opretion systems on one pc ,win 7 and ubuntu 16.04 .
After  disconnecting from ubuntu and boot to  win 7,
 the display time show 2 hours delay .

please advise how to solve this problem .

Comment: This question has a solution here [Clock shows wrong time after switching from Ubuntu to Windows 10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/800914/clock-shows-wrong-time-after-switching-from-ubuntu-to-windows-10)