# Ubuntu 18.04: Wired connection stops working within 10 minutes after boot

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, connection, wired

The wired connection stops working within 10 minutes after boot. I'm using MikroTik router, DHCP lease time is set to 10 minutes. It works again when i turn off/on my network in the menu (18:10:35 in log), no more issues until next reboot.

Log (router):

```
18:00:00 interface,info ether4 link up (speed 1G, full duplex) 

18:00:05 dhcp,info defconf deassigned 192.168.1.171 from 4C:CC:6A:69:5E:71 

18:00:05 dhcp,info defconf assigned 192.168.1.171 to 4C:CC:6A:69:5E:71 

18:10:05 dhcp,info defconf deassigned 192.168.1.171 from 4C:CC:6A:69:5E:71 

18:10:35 dhcp,info defconf assigned 192.168.1.171 to 4C:CC:6A:69:5E:71
```

Log (cat /var/log/syslog | grep -Ei 'dhcp'):

```
Jun 30 18:10:25 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371425.8435] dhcp4 (eno1): canceled DHCP transaction, DHCP client pid 1918
Jun 30 18:10:25 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371425.8436] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed bound -> done
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371430.1597] dhcp4 (eno1): activation: beginning transaction (timeout in 45 seconds)
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371430.1623] dhcp4 (eno1): dhclient started with pid 4729
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc dhclient[4729]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.171 on eno1 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7de82b3f)
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc dhclient[4729]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.171 from 192.168.1.1
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371430.2035] dhcp4 (eno1):   address 192.168.1.171
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371430.2035] dhcp4 (eno1):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371430.2035] dhcp4 (eno1):   gateway 192.168.1.1
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371430.2035] dhcp4 (eno1):   lease time 600
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371430.2036] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371430.2036] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserver '194.50.85.5'
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371430.2036] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserver '194.50.85.7'
Jun 30 18:10:30 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371430.2036] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed unknown -> bound
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc dhclient[4729]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.1.171 on eno1 to 192.168.1.1 port 67 (xid=0x7de82b3f)
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc dhclient[4729]: DHCPACK of 192.168.1.171 from 192.168.1.1
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371703.5592] dhcp4 (eno1):   address 192.168.1.171
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371703.5593] dhcp4 (eno1):   plen 24 (255.255.255.0)
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371703.5593] dhcp4 (eno1):   gateway 192.168.1.1
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371703.5593] dhcp4 (eno1):   lease time 600
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371703.5594] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserver '192.168.1.1'
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371703.5594] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserver '194.50.85.5'
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371703.5594] dhcp4 (eno1):   nameserver '194.50.85.7'
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc NetworkManager[1309]: <info>  [1530371703.5594] dhcp4 (eno1): state changed bound -> bound
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [eno1]: new request (1 scripts)
Jun 30 18:15:03 desconocido-pc nm-dispatcher: req:1 'dhcp4-change' [eno1]: start running ordered scripts...
```

Fresh install (except, probably, compiling libusb), works fine on Windows.
How can i fix it without increasing DHCP lease-time nor assigning static IP? Thank you.

Comment: Why is your lease time set to 10 minutes? That defeats the whole purpose. Edit your question to show us **sudo lshw -c network**.

Comment: @heynnema I can't edit settings on this router. Would it make any difference except postponing the issue?  [output](https://pastebin.com/4AkayuVi)

Comment: Probably i found the cause of this problem - i have dual boot configuration, Windows and Ubuntu. I didn't set the UTC offset on Windows, so when i booting to Windows after Ubuntu, my system clock is off by 3 hours. Then, when i boot Ubuntu again, it gets an IP, schedules next update on 'now + 10 minutes', synchronizes clock via the internet which in turn postpones the next DHCP update by 3 hours. Gonna check how far this is from truth.

Answer (score -1):

The cause of the problem was the [Multiple Boot Systems Time Conflicts](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuTime#Multiple_Boot_Systems_Time_Conflicts).
I'm guessing it works something like (i have no clues how it actually implemented):

1. System clock / time zone was changed by Windows.
2. Ubuntu boots up.
3. It obtains networks settings by DHCP.
4. It schedules next update at some point in time  using system clock.
5. You now connected to internet, OS synchronizes system clock. Previously mentioned time point isn't valid anymore.
6. The settings gets expired, but renewal is now delayed.

So if you have:

1. Dual boot configuration
2. System clock time is incorrect if you boot Windows after Ubuntu
3. Ubuntu fails to renew network settings once initial lease gets expired, although it works fine if you toggle your network on and off

The ultimate solution is:  **timedatectl set-local-rtc 1**

Source: https://askubuntu.com/a/800965/845325