# Fail to boot, suspect filesystem problem

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2

I have a Asus UX305F which has been dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows successfully using GRUB.  Today I started my computer, and it hung on the Ubuntu loading screen for 15 minutes so I hard powered it off.

When I powered it on again, it failed to boot and outputted the following error message to the screen:

```
[Firmware Bug]: TSC_DEADLINE disabled due to Errata: please update microcode to version: 0x25 (or later)
Error parsing PCC subspaces from PCCT
ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
ata1: COMRESET failed (errno=-16)
```

I then tried to reboot again, and it would only boot into Windows without bringing up GRUB at all.  I was able to use Windows successfully so this makes me think it is not a disk hardware issue.  I went into the BIOS settings, and didn't see the previous option boot device option I had used for dual booting anymore.

I plugged in an Ubuntu Live USB, which seemed to give me the option to boot into the Ubuntu Partition on my laptop SSD.  When I did that I got a bunch of errors:

```
ata1: failed to read log page 10h (errno=-5)
ata1.00: exception Emask 0x1 SAct 0x78000001 SErr 0x0action 0x6 frozen
ata1.00: irq_stat 0x4000008
ata1.00: failed command: READ FPDMA QUEUED
ata1.00: cmd 60/08:00:98:05:55/00:00:11:00:00/40 tag 0 ncq dma 4096 in
res 40/00:04:98:05:55/00:00:11:00:00/40 Emask 0x1 (device error)
ata1.00: status: { DRDY }
```

then later I see many errors below (dev/sda5 is my ext4 partition that has Ubuntu):

```
EXT4-fs error (device sda5): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4619: inode #10223617: block 40894496: comm systemd-tmpfile: unable to read itable block
EXT4-fs (sda5): previous I/O error to superblock detected
Buffer I/O error on dev sda5, logical block 0, lost sync page write
```

I booted to the Ubuntu Live USB and ran:

```
$ sudo fsck /dev/sda5
fsck from util-linux 2.31.1
e2fsck 1.44.1 (24-Mar-2018)
Superblock last mount time is in the future
    (by less than a day, probably due to the hardware clock being incorrectly set)
/dev/sda5: clean, 998052/10625024 files, 34573150/42472704 blocks
```

so it looks like the filesystem isn't corrupted.  When I ran it again later, it didn't have the message about mount time in the future.  I then mounted sda5 and it looks okay (though my home directory doesn't have the file contents but I suspect that is due to using ecryptfs).

Because I didn't see the GRUB menu I previously had, I thought it might be due to the boot loader being corrupted.

I ran boot repair, first to print out the info:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wzKqgwvbFS/

Here is the info after doing the repair:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zNhdsM8fxm/

What could be going on?  How could I fix it?

Comment: Take al look https://askubuntu.com/questions/800914/clock-shows-wrong-time-after-switching-from-ubuntu-to-windows-10