# Just downloaded Ubuntu alongside Windows 10 - Audio Issues STILL NO SOLUTION

Tags: sound, speakers, timezone

I just downloaded Ubuntu alongside Windows 10. I don't have these problems while using Ubuntu when I boot into Windows 10, suddenly my speakers are popping when they are initialized.

HP dvt-7000 custom built 
Beats Speakers (I have an IDT HD Audio CODEC driver that I had to install separately when I upgrade to Windows 10. The speakers do not work up to par in Ubuntu probably due to this, but they don't pop in Ubuntu, only in Windows 10)

Please help!! I've tried rebooting the system and disabling and re-enabling the speakers.

UPDATE: Time issue resolved itself because I had to reinstall Ubuntu. Audio issue still persists

UPDATE: I uninstalled and reinstalled the audio drive and it worked. Then, about a few days ago, the issue began again. I noted that the audio sounded different too, not the good quality I should be getting with the Beats. I uninstalled and reinstalled the driver again, but this time it did not solve the problem. Help!

Comment: This seems to be about Windows, not Ubuntu. Please see [Super User](http://www.superuser.com).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clock time is off on dual boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot)

Comment: @NoOneIsHere I've posted the question on Super User but no answers. Plus, I've received 2 downvotes. http://superuser.com/questions/1124865/just-downloaded-ubuntu-alongside-windows-10-speakers-are-now-popping

Comment: @cuhrisay The downvotes might be caused by formal issues only. For example, you _installed_ Ubuntu alongside Windows, just downloading would be not enough.

Answer (score 0):

First sorry if this is not the answer, I can't comment yet.

When you say the speaker are popping when they are initialized, you mean when you see the blue windows 10 logo during startup? Because it's in that moment when windows load all drivers (including audio drivers).

If you are hearing this poping when system start, with the welcome to windows audio, then this can be a problem of slow hard drive. Are you on SSD? Do you have so many programs loaded at start?

Also, can you hear this popping after some minutes of system start? when playiing any kind of audio? Maybe HP driver put on standby-resume state the audio. Have you check for updates on HP?

Even this is not for your problem, doing so can maybe help with it. Just download the .exe that fits with your system, instead of the mentioned on the link.

```
Try the following.

    Download the IDT Audio installer on the link below and save it to your Downloads folder.

    http://ftp.hp.com/pub/softpaq/sp59501-60000/sp59542.exe  

    When done, open windows Control Panel, open Device Manager and open up Sound, Video and Game Controllers.  Right click the IDT device and select Uninstall - you should also get a prompt to remove the current driver, tick the box to allow this and then proceed with the uninstall.

    When complete, shut down the notebook, unplug the AC Adapter and then remove the battery.  Hold  down the Power button for 30 seconds.  Re-insert the battery and plug in the AC Adapter.

    Tap away at the esc key as you start the notebook to launch the Start-up Menu and then select f10 to enter the bios menu.  Press f5 to load the defaults ( this is sometimes f9, but the menu at the bottom will show the correct key ), use the arrow keys to select 'Yes' and hit enter.  Press f10 to save the setting and again use the arrow keys to select 'Yes' and hit enter.

    Let Windows fully load - it will automatically load an audio driver, but just let this complete.  Then open your Downloads folder, right click on the IDT installer and select 'Run as Administrator' to start the installation.  When this has completed, right click the speaker icon in the Taskbar and select Playback Devices.  Left click 'Speakers and Headphones' once to highlight it and then click the Set Default button - check if you now have audio.

    Regards,
```

EDIT:

I see you are getting this poping everytime audio begins, then it points to a driver problem. You should completely uninstall this audio driver (mark **Delete the driver software for this device**), remove internet connection, install the .exe driver from HP for your windows 10 version, and if it does not exist try using windows 7 compatibily mode).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion! I am hearing the sound every time audio begins. For example. if I am watching YouTube videos, my speakers will pop when the video begins, and will pop when the next video begins. It also pops for every Windows Alert sound.

Comment: @cuhrisay  Edited answer with new info. Hope it helps.

Comment: my issue still persists. I had uninstalled the audio driver and it worked for a while. Just the other day, the issue started up again. Maybe due to updates. I reinstalled the driver again and ino luck. Any ideas?