# Ubuntu and Windows 10 dual boot

Tags: 14.04, windows, windows-10

I know that you can have two operating systems assuming no VM, virtutal machine, is being used. However, a friend of mine says that windows will get deleted for the next time it updates. The reason is that it recognizes the existence of another OS (Ubuntu) on the hard drive.

Is this true ? or similar to something that might be true ?

Thanks.

Comment: this is not true at all, if you follow the proper guides and as long as you don't delete your windows partition everything is gonna be fine, however while (or after) doing dual boot issues / problems can arise, but those issues are solvable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been running dual boot setups for more than 3 years now, on two different machines (laptops), with:

- Windows 8.1 alongside Ubuntu 12.04
- Windows 8.1 alongside Ubuntu 14.04
- Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 14.04
- Windows 10 alongside Ubuntu 16.04

So far I have not had any issues with any updates and I have regularly updated both Windows and Ubuntu.

On one of the machines I even made the (then free) upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10 and everything still works fine.

**EDIT:**

FWIW I never used the "install along other operating system" option during Ubuntu setup, but preferred to manually create the partition scheme. Obviously, if you choose to do this you should be super careful not to erase the Windows partition.

The two issues I ran into while using a dual boot setup were these:

- [BIOS clock conflict](https://askubuntu.com/a/169384/52404). The link also provides an easy way to fix this problem.
- Problem mounting partitions that are also used by Windows. This can easily be solved by turning off the Fast Startup option in Windows.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will upvote your post once I get enough reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Nop. Just make a ext4 partition. And while installing Ubuntu choose "install along other operating system" thn choose that ext4 partition and make it root. For better performance use swap. And for rearrange boot menu use grub-customizer

Comment: I will upvote your post once I get enough reputation. Thank  you!