# Ubuntu installation issues

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot

I am having Dell Inspiron i3 6th gen processor 4 gb ram and 1 tb hard disk with windows pre-installed in uefi mode.. Whenever I try to dual boot ubuntu in my laptop installation gets stuck at time zone selection zone. Please help. 
P. S. - I am connected to Internet while installing ubuntu

Comment: Have you changed from RAID to AHCI mode for drives in UEFI. Dell is unique in that you need CSM/BIOS mode on, but still boot in UEFI mode. Most then only boot in CSM mode. https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/19/SLN301754/how-to-install-ubuntu-and-a-recent-windows-operating-system-as-a-dual-boot-on-your-dell-pc?lang=EN & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2364642

Comment: I am having hdd not sdd

Answer (score 1):

Try disabling the internet connection while installing. This may very well be because of time-zone conflict if you're not in an area which follows UTC.

Windows assumes the hardware clock is giving your local time, whereas *nix systems assume it's giving the UTC time. So if you have internet on and you're not in the UTC zone, there will be a conflict between the current time of  your selected zone (gotten from the internet) and the hardware clock.

Once you have successfully installed Ubuntu you'll most probably face another issue if you have automatic time update on. After switching between Windows and Ubuntu you'll find the system clock in at least one of the operating systems is off by ±(UTC - your local time).

You may consult this Q&A to fix this issue:
[Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot)

Comment: thanks I am now not getting stuck at time zone selection step. But have encountered a new problem where ubuntu installation stops at process 'looking for other operating system' stating invalid access to FAT. Plz help.

Comment: @SumitBisht I myself haven't seen that error before. Googling "*looking for other operating system invalid access to FAT*" should bring up many Ask Ubuntu Q&As and ubuntuforums.org threads. See if those are helpful in your case.