# Time is wrong. Timezone must be changed

Tags: timezone

I have Ubuntu 17.10. I live in Finnland so when
I started the OP I choised finnish timezone.

But the time is 3 houres ahead.
I have to change timezone with someting like:
sudo dpkg-configure tmzone
to azores (in Atlantic ocean) to get wright time.

Comment: try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata` from terminal.  open a terminal with ctrl+alt+T.   (`sudo tzselect` will view timezones if needed but the dpkg-reconfigure step will change it)

Comment: Dual-boot system with Windows? Then see this: [Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot).

Answer (score 2):

To change time zone from terminal, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure tzdata
```

Once open, just follow the screens to change the time zone.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check if your **UTC** is correct? It happened to me once that the UTC was incorrect (there might be various reasons). It is easy to overlook because we just assume the UTC is correct. Type:

```
timedatectl
```

And, in many institutions/companies, the NTP servers are blocked so Ubuntu cannot acquire correct UTC, further leading to problems like what you observed.