# ubuntu 18.04 fix changing bios time

Tags: dual-boot

I have win10 (M2SSD)and ubuntu 18.04 (SSD) installed on separate hd, when I boot ubuntu, the time is correct as I have adjusted during installation, then I shot down ubuntu, and start with win 10 after boot up the time is Greenwich time. It is annoying to re correct the time after using ubuntu...
Any specific suggestion? (not interested in blog suggestions)
Best regards cyberdude...

Answer (score 3):

I believe this is a dupe of this question:

[Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot)

You need to either set Ubuntu to set the bios to local time (meh) per answer in above link:

```
$ sudo timedatectl set-local-rtc 1
```

or set Windo$e to use UTC time (preferred). This guide should help you:

[How to Fix Time Differences in Ubuntu 16.04 & Windows 10 Dual Boot](http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/time-differences-ubuntu-1604-windows-10/)