# How to prevent Live CD from changing hardware clock

Tags: clock, live-environment

The Live environment sets and writes the time in UTC to the hardware ("BIOS") clock. Which of course borks it for Windows. (see [Ubuntu bug 1703479](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntp/+bug/1703479))

Is there a boot option or similar to make it not do that?

Either:

- set it so use localtime in HW clock, or
- set it to never write to the HW clock (after all a live CD should not make changes to the system, at least not automatically)
- maybe some other solution

PS: The mentioned bug was reported for version 17.04, while it happened to me with 18.04 (ubuntu-18.04-desktop-amd64.iso).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot)

Comment: @N0rbert I disagree :) Dupe is about a normal install and has a fix. This is about a live session where you do not get the option to use those fixes as this is done during boot time from a read only medium.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a boot option or similar to make it not do that?

No.

> set it to never write to the HW clock (after all a live CD should not make changes to the system, at least not automatically)

This should be the case. A live session never ever ever should make permanent changes to a system. It defeats the purpose of a live session.
But this has been the case for a long time now so I expect Linux maintainers to have another idea about this. Using localtime is too limited anyway.

The live session is likely to run the following command

```
hwclock --systohc
```

and it will do this every time you start from the live session. If not that `/etc/default/rcS` will likely have `UTC=yes` as a parameter.

To prevent this from happening you would need to create your own live session ISO without adding either of these 2 settings.

The easier fix would be to tell Windows to use UTC instead of localtime. See for instance [howtogeek](https://www.howtogeek.com/323390/how-to-fix-windows-and-linux-showing-different-times-when-dual-booting/)'s method on how to do that. It is stupid to use localtime anyways as this does not support other operating systems than the one you are using.

Comment: Windows using localtime for the hardware clock is a hangover from the DOS days.

For details of how to fix it see https://superuser.com/questions/185773/does-windows-7-support-utc-as-bios-time

Comment: UTC on Windows does not work (correctly), so it is not an option. It would be nice if...
See: http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/mswish/ut-rtc.html

Comment: Yes it does. You can change it though a regex. I have done that 20+ times on windows systems and never found an issue with it.  Windows 7 and 10.