# Ubuntu 18.04 Clock not updating after Hibernate

Tags: 18.04, gnome, hibernate, reboot, clock

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my Laptop and use hibernate very often, but  if I resume, the clock in the top panel shows the wrong time. If I go to **Settings** > **Information** > **Date and Time** and toggle the *Determine date and time automatically* option twice the time gets updated correctly.

Is there any way to update the time automatically on resume after hibernate?  After reboot the clock in the top panel shows the correct time.

Comment: I would install ntp. But it may be not the best solution.

Comment: I found following solution working when machine is a dual boot widows and ubuntu http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2016/05/time-differences-ubuntu-1604-windows-10/

Comment: Related: [Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot)

Answer (score 1):

If you install `ntp` by

```
sudo apt install ntp
```

Your time will be always automatically synchronized with time servers.

Another way is to correct the service that brings the system up from hibernation to run `ntpdate`.

Comment: I installed `ntp`. If I hibernate just a few minutes it works. If I hibernate a day the time is some hours behind after resume.

Comment: It will catchup in a few minutes.