# Different timestamp when copying files between Windows and Linux

Tags: mount, windows, copy, timestamp

I'm using mount.cifs to map a windows folder, then I copy hundred of files at once from windows to Ubuntu.
After that all files are syncronized and the modification times as well.
On Windows using explorer I see that not all but a very few files have a difference of 1 hour from the copied files on Ubuntu.
Why on windows almost all files match the modification time but some do not?
*I had to edit this post to explain that I think it is not related to the UTC and it is not a duplicated question. I'm just comparing a list of over 2000 files with the filenames and timestamps, one file generated on Windows and one file generated on Linux. I compare these 2 files and then I copy only the modified files. Even these files were all updated I keep copying 14 files every time.*

Comment: Ubuntu uses UTC. Please check you have Windows also on UTC (by default it does not)

Comment: and probably the issue is this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot

Comment: Thanks Rinzwind, but this is not the same issue. This problems only happens with 14 of 2000 files I'm copying.

Comment: I'm going to try the UTC solution. Thanks.

Comment: try using `cp --preserve=timestamps --recursive /from/* /to/*` first.  Leave a comment @Fabby if that's the solution...