# ubuntu has a different time than the system time

Tags: time, date

My Ubuntu 18.04.3 date/time is 3:10 AM Feb 26, 2020. However the BIOS date/time is 8:10 AM Feb 25, 2020. If I correct the date/time in Ubuntu, it changes it on the BIOS, and viceversa. How can I solve this?

Comment: What locale are you using?

Comment: @Rinzwind I am using es_US.UTF-8

Comment: Is this a dual boot system?

Comment: No, it is not. Linux Mint 19.3 only.

Comment: Mint is off topic here!

Comment: Mint is based on Ubuntu.

Comment: Please read the **first bullet point** under [Questions that you should avoid](https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic) in this site's help page.

Comment: Linux Mint is not Ubuntu. It's off topic here http://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic "Questions that you should avoid: Linux Mint, Elementary OS, Backtrack, Gnome-Remix (prior to 13.04), budgie-remix (16.04 & 16.10) & other Linux distributions" There are _significant differences_ between Ubuntu and Mint. Many folks here will suggest you visit Mint Support  https://forums.linuxmint.com/ or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Linux and UTC

Your computer stores the time in a hardware clock on its motherboard. The clock keeps track of time, even when the computer is off. This is the time you see in the BIOS.

By default, Linux and other Unix systems sets the hardware time is in [Coordinated Universal Time (UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Then the time you see in Ubuntu as system time is offset according to the local timezone set. So if you don't live in UTC timezone or somewhere along prime meridian, the time you see in the BIOS will not match the time you see in Ubuntu.

## This not a bug. This is a feature.

This is not a problem unless you dualboot Ubuntu and Windows. Windows by default sets the hardware clock to local time. So, when you switch between Windows and Ubuntu, the hardware clock will be interpreted differently and you will see the "wrong" time in one system or the other. See [Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot) for how to fix this problem for dual boot systems.

Hope this helps

Comment: I thank you for your response, this is not a dual boot system. Nevertheless I will check your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

What about you time zone set up? You can get it from:
`timedatectl`

In case you want to sync the machine time with the network's time where the machine is accessing the internet

Did you tried to run 
`sudo timedatectl set-ntp on`

This commands will sync the time with the internet network time location

Comment: Yes, I tried it. Problem persists after that.

Comment: `echo "Europe/London" | sudo tee /etc/timezone # for setting up the time to London-UK;`

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure --frontend noninteractive tzdata;`

#Maybe this one ^^

Comment: Why would I try Europe/Lodon since I am in America?

Comment: No no, This is what I just did for me here in London...
You want to change that to your location ... (ZONE)

Comment: You can get the location zone from `timedatectl list-timezones` then update the command above before run on your terminal