# Clock time off on dualboot

Tags: time

so i got windows 10 pro and ubuntu 20.04.2 lts on my dell latitude e5450.
When i boot to ubuntu, then restart to windows 10, the time is wrong. It changes the bios time to +4 hours from now (UTC).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot)

Comment: Set Windows to UTC time: `Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00`

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation]`
`"RealTimeIsUniversal"=dword:00000001` Modify Registry at your own risk.

Comment: I do not have RealTimeIsUniversal

Answer (score 0):

You just need to configure Windows so the hardware clock is UTC.

Comment: Its set to utc-5

Comment: Better to use UTC. Then you don't need to bother with daylight time changes, and Linux always uses that. Should be easy to convince Win to do the same.

Comment: But its daylight saving where i am.

Comment: If hw time is UTC, the OS knows if there is daylight saving given your location and time of year. No changes need to be made at any time.

Comment: I do not have admin.

Comment: ??? You have no Admin rights on your own machine? This is a Win fault that must be corrected on that system.

Comment: My granddaddy put it on.

Comment: In that case, @Nimmam, ask him to give you admin rights. This must be fixed in windows. Best of luck :)

Comment: fixed - changed time zone for ubuntu and ubuntu time
Password is only on Windows, and i set my own password on Ubuntu.