# System time changes by 5½ hours after being suspended for a while

Tags: 22.04, suspend, time, clock

Every time I open my System(Ubuntu 22.04) from suspend, the system time is wrong, exactly by 5½ hours and this time is 11 hours ahead of GMT. For example, if the correct time is 3:30 PM, it shows 9:00 PM after opening from suspend. Is there any way to resolve this?

PS: The problem is not related to dual-boot, as I am not restarting the system. Just waking it up from suspend.

Comment: Is your timezone Indian time (UTC+0530)? Is the system dual boot with Windows?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot

Comment: @muru Yes, it is UTC+0530 and is dual boot with windows

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Clock time is off on dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/169376/clock-time-is-off-on-dual-boot)

Comment: Thanks @karel, for the suggestions. But the problem is not about the dual boot, as I am not restarting the system. After keeping it in suspend mode and waking it up again, the time issue occurs.

Comment: The problem will happen if you boot to Windows, then reboot (or shutdown), boot into Linux, suspend and then resume. So yes, please look into the dual boot issue in depth.